# Java apache poi to create pivot table from multiple excel sheets that have relationship to each other

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have 5 excel sheets that have relationship to each other (linked with ID) like this article https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/advanced-pivottables-combining-data-from-multiple-sheets--cms-21190.

I would like to use java with apache poi to create a pivot table from these multiple sheets.

Could you please suggest how i can achieve this? - to set relationship and generate a pivot table from these sheets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: by writing the code that links them to each other. this is not explained in a simple SO comment, nor should it be.

Comment: @Stultuske do we have poi interface to manage relationship (primary key -> foreign key) between sheets. Please suggest.